# Borders and equal height css columns

Tags: css, html, border

I have code like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="left">
      a profile pic and some text
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      a wider div with much more text and some bio info
  </div>
</div>
```

i would like a dotted border in between the two divs to separate the left column from the right.  my problem is that no matter if i put the border on the left column or the right column it doesn't stretch to the bottom. if either column is shorter/longer than the other the border always stops before reaching the bottom looking cut off.

Comment: you're missing a closing div tag BTW

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 html,body,.container, .section, .left, .right{height:100%}
  .left, .right {border:1px dotted black;float:left;}
```

example: http://jsbin.com/agaza5

Answer (score 0):

Set the height property equally for both divs columns using CSS:

```
.left {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:100px; /* you can use "100%" too, if you want */
}


.right {
    height:100px; /* you can use "100%" too, if you want */
}
```

You can also use the `min-height` attribute if you want to create the same minimum height for both divs, but let only one div stretch further if its content grows.

I would also add that you should use more semantic names for your divs. What if one day you decided to move your left column and it was no longer on the left? You would have to rename everything!

Comment: `display:block` will stack the DIVs instead of displaying them inline (floated). DIVs are already block-level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make both your left and right divs stretch the full height of the container (`section`).

```
.left{ height:100%; }
.right{ height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the height of your `section` div and then just set the children heights to 100%.

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/zTm5k/)

Comment: Oh, well I was showing that the Red is set to 100% and the blue isn't, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. The OP wanted the border "between" both DIVs to be as long as the tallest DIV (extend all the way down). I thought your link was an example of this.